# GWT run on External Server

Tags: java, gwt, external

I need to test my client application on an external server, with the development mode to a better debug.

i try to run in eclipse the application on the external server, but it doesn't run.

i realy need a step-by-step example

thanks for the help

Comment: May it will be helpfull http://clojure-dev.blogspot.com/2011/12/debugging-gwt-client-side-code-with.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [THIS](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html) page. There they have a command how to start your server with GWT debug mode on.

Than make sure your URL is pointed to the right server.

This is how it should look on your machine: 
`http://{local ip or host name}:8080/AppName/?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997`

This is what should be entered on the external clint on the same network: 
`http://[YOUR-IP]:8080/AppName/?gwt.codesvr=[YOUR-IP]:9997`

Make sure both ports are matching. Mine is running 8080 because I'm running Java server, you might have different port.